# xcode4 - scheme test problem

Tags: c++, xcode4

How do you run your code to run through all scheme test cases in xcode4?

"the scheme '/name/' is not configured for testing. Edit the scheme to configure testing,... "

But I cant seem to set it up to test all the scheme cases.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use the schemes that Xcode installed when you created the project: they have the test phase already configured. To execute the test, choose menu Product -> Test.